# Get the context of a user in dynamics crm

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a list of users in dynamics crm, I want when I create the context of crm will have only the context of one user, ie the user will not have the access to records of other users.

i have try to change the caller of the organizationproxy like this:

```
                //original context
                OrganizationServiceContext contextORI = new OrganizationServiceContext(organisationProxy);
                //i search th user
                Utilisateur user= (from k in contextORI.CreateQuery<Utilisateur>()
                                    where k.Id == User.Id
                                    select k).FirstOrDefault();
                //i change the caller of organisationProxy
                this.organisationProxy.CallerId = user.Id;
                //i create the new context
                OrganizationServiceContext context = new OrganizationServiceContext(organisationProxy);
```

but the user have always the access to all results

when I have verified with the WhoAmIRequest, I still find the old user.

Do you have any idea how can switch th users?

Comment: Are the security roles properly setup ? Have you tried issuing a WhoAmIRequest to make sure the user is effectively being switched ?

Comment: I have verified with the WhoAmIRequest, I still find the old user

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your user don't have **prvActOnBehalfOfAnotherUser** privilege in assigned security role.

> User account (A) needs the privilege prvActOnBehalfOfAnotherUser, which is included in the Delegate role.
>
> Alternately, for Active Directory directory service deployments only, user account (A) under which the impersonation code is to run can be added to the PrivUserGroup group in Active Directory. This group is created by Microsoft Dynamics CRM during installation and setup. User account (A) does not have to be associated with a licensed Microsoft Dynamics CRM user. However, the user who is being impersonated (B) must be a licensed Microsoft Dynamics CRM user.
>
> The actual set of privileges that is used to modify data is the intersection of the privileges that the Delegate role user possesses with that of the user that is being impersonated. In other words, user A is allowed to do something if and only if user A and the impersonated user (B) have the privilege necessary for the action.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334744.aspx)

Comment: Please add such suggestions as a comment!

Comment: Ok. In other words you should ensure that initial user has security role with **prvActOnBehalfOfAnotherUser** privilege.